# I am getting an error, how to resolve it?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, marketing-cloud-connect

I am getting an error on my signup page:

`The Data Extension name for a LookupRows function call is invalid.`

`A Data Extension of this name does not exist.`

`Data Extension Name: LinksByBrand Function Call: LookupRows("LinksByBrand", "Brand", @brand) Parameter Name: DataExtensionName Parameter Ordinal: 1`

I cant figure out what ("**LinksByBrand**", "Brand", @brand) parameters we must be using instead on the one in bold?

Comment: by data Extension what do you mean? Is it a package?

Comment: I have no idea. This is a random error the page started giving and i assume is a database.

Comment: which signup page are you refering to? Isit a custom VF page?

Answer (score 0):

That's a Salesforce Marketing Cloud (SFMC) [AMPScript](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/) error.  It means the SFMC landing page doesn't have the value for the `@brand` variable that it needs to retrieve a row from the `LinksByBrand` Data Extension (database table).

To troubleshoot it, you'll need access to the SFMC account that's hosting this particular [Microsite](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/microsites/) or [Landing Page](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/landing_pages/).

Reference:
[LookupRows()](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/data_extension_ampscript_functions/#LookupRows)